# What are the rights of a women over her husband?

Tags: husband, wife

There are a lot of questions regarding the rights of a man over a woman, but there are also so many rights that a man must fulfill to his wife! What are they?

Comment: they are a lot and better look this book: http://www.al-islam.org/womanrights/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I dont want to know what Qadianis think. That website is from the Ahmadi Qadiani community who are not of the Ahlus Sunnah neither are they from the Shia.

Comment: you are wrong. this site is not from Ahmadi Qadiani. this site has many content against them. you should not who are real Ahlus Sunnah http://www.al-islam.org/real/

Answer (score 5):

the quran says that both the husband and wife have rights over one another

> “And they (women) have rights (over their husbands as regards living expenses) similar (to those of their husbands) over them (as regards obedience and respect) to what is reasonable” [al-Baqarah 2:228]

firstly, before the marrige is placed a husband must give his wife a dowery or mahr, it is money or somthing of value given to a women before marrige

> “And give to the women (whom you marry) their Mahr (obligatory bridal-money given by the husband to his wife at the time of marriage) with a good heart” [al-Nisaa’ 4:4]

the quran also says that a man must spend on his wife and children as part of the marrige contract

> “but the father of the child shall bear the cost of the mother’s food and clothing on a reasonable basis” [al-Baqarah 2:233]

the prophet also instructed many times to treat your wife with kindness

> "Treat women well. The woman was created from a rib. The most bent part of the rib is the top part. If you try to straighten it, you will break it. If you leave it, it remains bent. So treat women well.bukhari
>
> ‘Be kind to women.’”(Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 3153; Muslim, 1468).
>
> "No Mu'min (believer) should dislike his believing wife. If he does not like her attitude (in some matters), (then) he will like another." [Muslim].

in conclusion a man should protect his wife, be kind to her, and  pay for her expenses as part of an islamic marital contract.