# What is recommended behaviour and the rights of a wife, If her husband is sinful and wouldn't give up?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife

My husband is very Islamic, but chats online with unknown girls, even requesting "space and privacy".  He sometimes talks to them for a whole day, which I find disturbing.  I have asked him to stop, but it leads to fights.

What are my Islamic rights as a wife in this situation?

Comment: This website is not for peer support or family counseling.

Comment: Is that similar to Zina of the tongue ???

Answer (score 2):

You have the right to stop him. As explained in the following hadith:

Narrated By Abu Sa’eed al-Khudree.

> I heard the Messenger of Allah (pbuh) say, “Whosoever of you sees an evil, let him change it with his hand; and if he is not able to do so, then [let him change it] with his tongue; and if he is not able to do so, then with his heart — and that is the weakest of faith.” [[Muslim]](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40/34)

If the recommendation for an ordinary person who may not have any relation with the one who commits evil is to stop it by Hand, tongue and so on,..., you are his wife, and your place is extraordinary, because you have more rights over him. If your husband wouldn't stop committing evil, and would not listen to you then he is a disobedient husband and in clear violation of the Quran.

> And live with them (women) in kindness
>   [Quran 4:19](http://And%20live%20with%20them%20in%20kindness)

Explain your rights to him and the violation he is making. Ask for someone to mediate this issue. Someone from within his family like his Wali.
If everything fails then his position as a husband becomes void, based on the above Quranic verse that he is not following. 
You may initiate Faskh. Faskh is a kind of divorce which is initiated by the wife regardless of the consent of her husband.

Comment: Thanks for my help... Plz explain... What are my Rights to my husband and what are his Rights to me... According to quran and hadith

Comment: Sir please explain what are my Rights to my husband and what are his to me?...With reference to quran and hadith..

Comment: @Shafia Please take a look at these questions to know your rights. [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-are-the-rights-of-a-women-over-her-husband) 
and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26328/what-are-the-duties-of-a-husband)